# NavHostFragment crashes in onDestroyView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-navigationview

I have a single `Activity` app with a `FragmentContainerView` and a `BottomNavigationView` setup:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/splash" />

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:elevation="12dp"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_nav_main" />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

When the user enters the app I need to show a splash page(and onboarding if requires) and then navigate it to the home page. so I have created 4 nav-graphs, 1 for the splash, and 3 for the bottom nav. I'm using [this](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/NavigationAdvancedSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/navigationadvancedsample/NavigationExtensions.kt) extinction from android samples to setup the bottom nav with 3 graphs. here is my `MainActivity` code:

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : BaseActivity<ActivityMainBinding, MainViewModel>(
    R.layout.activity_main,
    MainViewModel::class,
) {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        if (!vm.splashPassed) {
            val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
            currentNavController = MutableLiveData(navHostFragment.navController)
        } else if (savedInstanceState == null && vm.splashPassed) {
            naviagateToHome()
        }
    }

    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
        if (vm.splashPassed) {
            naviagateToHome()
        }
    }

    fun naviagateToHome() {
        vm.splashPassed = true
        val fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .remove(fragment)
            .commitNow()

        setupBottomNavigationBar()
    }

    private lateinit var currentNavController: LiveData<NavController>

    private fun setupBottomNavigationBar() {
        binding.bottomNavigation.isVisible = true
        val navGraphIds = arrayListOf(R.navigation.explore, R.navigation.plan, R.navigation.profile)

        // Setup the bottom navigation view with a list of navigation graphs
        currentNavController = binding.bottomNavigation.setupWithNavController(
            navGraphIds = navGraphIds,
            fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager,
            containerId = R.id.nav_host_fragment,
            intent = intent,
        )
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        val navController = currentNavController.value ?: return super.onBackPressed()

        if (navController.graph.id == R.id.splash) return super.onBackPressed()

        val destination = navController.currentDestination?.id
        val rootDestinations = listOf(R.id.planFragment, R.id.profileFragment, R.id.exploreFragment, R.id.panelFragment)
        if (destination !in rootDestinations && navController.navigateUp()) return

        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

and here's how I call `naviagateToHome` from `SplashFragment`:

```kotlin
vm.navigateHome.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
    (requireActivity() as? MainActivity)?.naviagateToHome()
}
```

Everything works fine until the `Activity` performs `onDestroy`(when it has been pushed to the background) and it crashes with the following stack trace:

> 2020-09-13 13:17:38.064 28092-28092/com.abc.dev E/AndroidRuntime:
> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.abc.dev, PID: 28092
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.abc.dev/com.abc.ui.activity.MainActivity}:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: View
> androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView{e7a7304 V.E...... ......ID
> 0,0-1080,1868 #7f0a026a app:id/nav_host_fragment} does not have a
> NavController set
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4941)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4970)
> at android.app.servertransaction.DestroyActivityItem.execute(DestroyActivityItem.java:44)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: View androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView{e7a7304 V.E...... ......ID
> 0,0-1080,1868 #7f0a026a app:id/nav_host_fragment} does not have a
> NavController set
> at androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController(Navigation.java:84)
> at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onDestroyView(NavHostFragment.java:388)
> at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performDestroyView(Fragment.java:3171)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.destroyFragmentView(FragmentStateManager.java:726)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:360)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1632)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3109)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchDestroy(FragmentManager.java:3088)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchDestroy(FragmentController.java:334)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onDestroy(FragmentActivity.java:322)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onDestroy(AppCompatActivity.java:278)
> at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:8048)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1334)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4926)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4970) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.DestroyActivityItem.execute(DestroyActivityItem.java:44) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)

After spending some time to debug I realized the `androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onDestroyView` tries to use `Navigation.findNavController` method which has some problems described [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142847973#comment15). I also find a [pull request](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/pull/887) on the android/architecture-components-samples GitHub repository which doesn't offer any clear solution.

**note:**
If I setup the bottom nav in `onCreate` by calling `setupBottomNavigationBar` I don't get the error and everything goes well.

I have stuck for more than one week and I have no clue how to fix it.

tnx for reading my long question.

**Update 1:**
I have noticed if I change the selected bottom nav item at least once, the crash doesn't occur.

Also if I add a custom animation when I want to detach the previous `NavHostFragment` which is the splash as follow, the same error occurs all the time:

```
fun naviagateToHome() {
    vm.splashPassed = true
    val fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.nav_default_enter_anim, R.anim.nav_default_exit_anim)
        .remove(fragment)
        .commitNow()

    setupBottomNavigationBar()
}
```

> 2020-09-14 00:18:37.705 3434-3434/com.abc.dev E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
> EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.abc.dev, PID: 3434
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: View androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView{1414b18 V.E...... ......ID
> 0,0-1080,1868 #7f0a026a app:id/nav_host_fragment} does not have a
> NavController set
> at androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController(Navigation.java:84)
> at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onDestroyView(NavHostFragment.java:388)
> at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performDestroyView(Fragment.java:3171)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.destroyFragmentView(FragmentStateManager.java:726)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:360)
> at androidx.fragment.app.SpecialEffectsController$FragmentStateManagerOperation.complete(SpecialEffectsController.java:512)
> at androidx.fragment.app.DefaultSpecialEffectsController.removeCancellationSignal(DefaultSpecialEffectsController.java:81)
> at androidx.fragment.app.DefaultSpecialEffectsController$4$1.run(DefaultSpecialEffectsController.java:255)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)

Comment: Why are you manually running FragmentTransactions if you are using NavHostFragment?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I want to switch change the whole nav graph to another, how can I achieve that without manual transaction?

Comment: Tbh you should have 1 graph that includes your other XMLs with `<include` and just use actions to move between graphs.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce currently Navigation Component doesn't support multiple back stacks, so as suggested in [this](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample) sample we need multiple nav graphs, and I have 1 other for the rest of my app. checkout [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80029773) issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the part of code in navigation sample that decides which fragment to attach and detach the other fragments.

```
    // Attach or detach nav host fragment depending on whether it's the selected item.
    if (this.selectedItemId == graphId) {
        selectedNavController.value = navHostFragment.navController
            attachNavHostFragment(fragmentManager, navHostFragment, index == 0)
    } else {
        detachNavHostFragment(fragmentManager, navHostFragment)
    }
```

**What is happening here?**
**attach** : when NavHostFragment is attached with container it's
`onViewCreated` is called, which also setup the NavController for parent view i.e. FragmentContainerView in this case.

**detach**: when NavHostFragment is detached from container `onDestroyView` is called. `onDestroyView` sets the NavController to null for parent view.

`attach` is called only for `selectedFragmentId`, and all other fragments are detached.

Here are the logs for you case, considering the first fragment as selected fragment:

```
2020-09-14 09:34:58.602 12023-12023/com.beetlestance.testingnavigation D/navHostLifecycle: onDestroyView
2020-09-14 09:34:58.602 12023-12023/com.beetlestance.testingnavigation D/navController: SplashFragment removing navController from parent
2020-09-14 09:34:58.611 12023-12023/com.beetlestance.testingnavigation D/bottomSheet: obtain navHostFragment 1
2020-09-14 09:34:58.616 12023-12023/com.beetlestance.testingnavigation D/navHostLifecycle: onCreate
2020-09-14 09:34:58.620 12023-12023/com.beetlestance.testingnavigation D/navHostLifecycle: onViewCreated
2020-09-14 09:34:58.620 12023-12023/com.beetlestance.testingnavigation D/navController: FirstBottomFragment setting navController to parent
2020-09-14 09:34:58.633 12023-12023/com.beetlestance.testingnavigation D/navHostLifecycle: onResume
2020-09-14 09:34:58.634 12023-12023/com.beetlestance.testingnavigation D/bottomsheet: attach 1
2020-09-14 09:34:58.635 12023-12023/com.beetlestance.testingnavigation D/bottomSheet: obtain navHostFragment 2
2020-09-14 09:34:58.640 12023-12023/com.beetlestance.testingnavigation D/navHostLifecycle: onCreate
2020-09-14 09:34:58.643 12023-12023/com.beetlestance.testingnavigation D/navHostLifecycle: onViewCreated
2020-09-14 09:34:58.643 12023-12023/com.beetlestance.testingnavigation D/navController: SecondBottomFragment setting navController to parent
2020-09-14 09:34:58.654 12023-12023/com.beetlestance.testingnavigation D/navHostLifecycle: onResume
2020-09-14 09:34:58.656 12023-12023/com.beetlestance.testingnavigation D/bottomsheet: detach 2
2020-09-14 09:34:58.660 12023-12023/com.beetlestance.testingnavigation D/navHostLifecycle: onDestroyView
2020-09-14 09:34:58.660 12023-12023/com.beetlestance.testingnavigation D/navController: SecondBottomFragment removing navController from parent
2020-09-14 09:34:58.661 12023-12023/com.beetlestance.testingnavigation D/bottomSheet: obtain navHostFragment 3
2020-09-14 09:34:58.666 12023-12023/com.beetlestance.testingnavigation D/navHostLifecycle: onCreate
2020-09-14 09:34:58.668 12023-12023/com.beetlestance.testingnavigation D/navHostLifecycle: onViewCreated
2020-09-14 09:34:58.668 12023-12023/com.beetlestance.testingnavigation D/navController: ThirdBottomFragment setting navController to parent
2020-09-14 09:34:58.678 12023-12023/com.beetlestance.testingnavigation D/navHostLifecycle: onResume
2020-09-14 09:34:58.680 12023-12023/com.beetlestance.testingnavigation D/bottomsheet: detach 3
2020-09-14 09:34:58.684 12023-12023/com.beetlestance.testingnavigation D/navHostLifecycle: onDestroyView
2020-09-14 09:34:58.684 12023-12023/com.beetlestance.testingnavigation D/navController: ThirdBottomFragment removing navController from parent
```

From the logs it is clear that the detach is the last call instead of attach, which causes parent NavController to be null.

**Solution:**
Selected fragment should be attached in the end, which will solve the issue here. In case you have different selected id by default for bottom navigation you can just attach the fragment outside of forEach loop instead of reversing the list.

Another approach would be to attach your bottom sheet inside of a fragment, which will simplify most of you cases. Splash fragment will always be the start destination which the navigate to you bottom navigation container fragment that will setup bottom sheet in it's `onViewCreated`. Check https://github.com/beetlestance/android-extensions

**Why does it work when setup in `onCreate`?**

The fragment are attached or detached only when the activity is at least started. So when you setup bottom navigation in onCreate the lifecycle of NavHostFragment is different.

The logs in case bottom navigation is setup in `onCreate`:

```
2020-09-14 10:07:17.659 15260-15260/com.beetlestance.testingnavigation D/bottomSheet: obtain navHostFragment 1
2020-09-14 10:07:18.011 15260-15260/com.beetlestance.testingnavigation D/navHostLifecycle: onCreate
2020-09-14 10:07:18.017 15260-15260/com.beetlestance.testingnavigation D/bottomsheet: attach 1
2020-09-14 10:07:18.041 15260-15260/com.beetlestance.testingnavigation D/bottomSheet: obtain navHostFragment 2
2020-09-14 10:07:18.069 15260-15260/com.beetlestance.testingnavigation D/navHostLifecycle: onCreate
2020-09-14 10:07:18.073 15260-15260/com.beetlestance.testingnavigation D/bottomsheet: detach 2
2020-09-14 10:07:18.077 15260-15260/com.beetlestance.testingnavigation D/bottomSheet: obtain navHostFragment 3
2020-09-14 10:07:18.098 15260-15260/com.beetlestance.testingnavigation D/navHostLifecycle: onCreate
2020-09-14 10:07:18.108 15260-15260/com.beetlestance.testingnavigation D/bottomsheet: detach 3
2020-09-14 10:07:18.173 15260-15260/com.beetlestance.testingnavigation D/mainActivityLifecycle: onStart
2020-09-14 10:07:18.208 15260-15260/com.beetlestance.testingnavigation D/navHostLifecycle: onViewCreated
2020-09-14 10:07:18.208 15260-15260/com.beetlestance.testingnavigation D/navController: FirstBottomFragment setting navController to parent
2020-09-14 10:07:18.292 15260-15260/com.beetlestance.testingnavigation D/mainActivityLifecycle: onResume
2020-09-14 10:07:18.304 15260-15260/com.beetlestance.testingnavigation D/navHostLifecycle: onResume
```

As you can check `onDestroyView` for NavHostFragment is not called. So NavController is correctly setup.

Hopefully this will help.

Comment: I got your point, I just attached the default fragment outside of the for loop, tnx

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused when detach is called in the end instead of attach, which forces navController to be null on parent NavHostFragment.

Comment: I put the link in the question, here it is again: https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/NavigationAdvancedSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/navigationadvancedsample/NavigationExtensions.kt

Comment: @Mosius The crash can be solved by replacing `navGraphIds.forEachIndexed` with `navGraphIds.reversed().forEachIndexed` and maintaining the `firsFragmentId`. The issue is happening as you are setting up bottomsheet after onResume of activity.

Comment: [https://github.com/beetlestance/android-extensions](https://github.com/beetlestance/android-extensions) Check this sample

Comment: I can't understand why reversing the list would help? by the way, I have a different default item selected(the center item), so I can't use the last index.

Comment: Don't forgot to change this line if you reverse the list `if (index == navGraphIds.lastIndex) {firstFragmentGraphId = graphId}`

Comment: @NijatAhmadli note is important. If you don't do it, if your first click is on the last item, it won't work.